# Open form B that has a subform based on form A

Tags: vba, ms-access

Form A has a button that opens form B which has a continuous subform which needs to filter records based on a field in form A.

The code attached produces the error: runtime error '2491'
The action or method is invalid because the form or report isnt bound to a table or query

I suspect the continuous form is the problem as it doesn't appear in the Access forms list but it does have a name in form B however I don't know how to reference it.

Form B is opened from elsewhere without a filter so I don't want to change form B.

CODE:
... DoCmd.OpenForm Formname:="B",wherecondition:="woid = " Forms!A!cmbowoid.Column(0)

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: Form B has no RecordSource. Only the subform under B does. When you execute the `OpenForm` method on Form B, you get the error because the `WhereCondition` has no records to act on. The `WhereCondition` has no knowledge of (and no effect on) B's subform.
The fix:

1) Use OpenArgs:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Formname:="B", OpenArgs:="woid = " Forms!A!cmbowoid.Column(0)
```

2) In Form B's `Form_Load` event, enter this code:

```
Me.subFormB.Filter = Me.OpenArgs
```

As long as your `OpenArgs` is a valid Filter expression, this should work.

Comment: Hi kismert, Thanks.  I see how that will work I have created a new subform which, not as good as your solution, works.  I will change to your solution.